# Is this basic proof complete?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have a problem with proving that the limit as x goes to infinity for lnx/x is 0. Take the most basic approach:

Note that the derivative of lnx is 1/x whereas x has a derivative of 1. Hence,  lnx is outgrown by x as x assumes larger and larger values (basically concavity). Hence, lnx/x will crash to 0. Or will it??

Clearly the function is asymptotic. But is this by itself proof? Have we truly established that it is asymptotic to precisely 0?

I know this may sound a bit ridiculous, but needs there not to also be a step establishing that it will also be asymptotic to 0?

Additionally, how would one carry out such a logical step?

Comment: What you just described was [L'hopital's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln x}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}$, which asymptotes to $\infty$.